# Set PDF to print with no scaling

Tags: pdf, printing, fpdf

I am generating a PDF (using fpdf) and I am wondering if there is a way to set the document's properties to to default to print with no scaling.

So when you select print from the print dialogue menu, scaling is set to none. I'm trying to determine if this is a user setting or something I can control in the creation of the PDF.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scaling is controlled by the PDF application - it is not set in the file.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Is this something that could be achieved by writing a plugin and having the user install the plugin?

Comment: You could ship your own viewer or plugin but it would be a lot of work and you would have to guarantee the user had to use it

Comment: This answer is misleading. There is a way to embed a preference in the file to request no scaling. Most PDF applications will honour the preference and not scale the document as a result.

Comment: You can have a default scaling on a page but it can also be adjusted by the user (and by actions in the  PDF). Viewers like Acrobat also allow multiple print options and views.

Answer (score 10):

I've done it adding to the method `_putcatalog()` the following:

```
$this->_out('/ViewerPreferences [/PrintScaling/None]');
```

After the line:

```
$this->_out('/Type /Catalog');
```

Implementing a method is just fast and easy...

Comment: A variation of this worked for me. I subclassed FPDF and overrode _putcatalog() to output "/ViewerPreferences <</PrintScaling /None>>" after its existing output.

Comment: When I used ReportLab's ``setViewerPreferences('PrintScaling', 'None')`` it generated the line ``/ViewerPreferences 12 0 R`` and added ``12 0 obj
<< /PrintScaling /None >>`` further down the page. The other possible value seems to be ``/PrintScaling /AppDefault``.

Answer (score 8):

Print-scaling can be turned off for invividual PDF files using Adobe Acrobat, by going to File -> Preferences -> Advanced -> Page scaling. (You can try this using the trial version of Acrobat.)

As for achieving this in code, I've tried and failed to make it work, but the critical difference in the files seems to be:

```
10 0 obj
<</Metadata 2 0 R/Outlines 6 0 R/Pages 7 0 R/Type/Catalog/ViewerPreferences<</PrintScaling/None>>>>
endobj
```

for non-scaling PDFs, compared to

```
10 0 obj
<</Metadata 2 0 R/Outlines 6 0 R/Pages 7 0 R/Type/Catalog>>
endobj
```

for those that use the default shrink-to-fit option.

Comment: Hi, this is a bit of a stretch, but how would I use this with Exiftool - http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/

Answer (score 2):

For me changing the FPDF Catalog method _putcatalog() and adding

```
    $this->_out('/ViewerPreferences [/PrintScaling/None]');
```

wasn't accomplishing the goal so I looked at the code produced by a Acrobate XI PDF and found some more verbage. Adding the following code

```
    $this->_out('/ViewerPreferences<</Duplex/Simplex/Enforce[/PrintScaling]/PrintScaling/None>>');
```

created a PDF that no longer defaulted to scaling and instead only gave the option to print Actual Size which was what was desired.

Comment: Where in the function did you put this?  At the end or as suggested by onosenday's answer, after the "/Type /Catalog" output?

Answer (score -1):

well i'm not sure if you mean somethink like this:
http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/setdisplaymode.htm

or no "scaling" for images?

```
$im2 = pdf_open_image_file($dokument, 'jpeg', 'example.jpg');
pdf_place_image($dokument, $im2, 395, 655, 1.0); /* 1.0 = qualiti/scaling - 1.0 is original .../*
pdf_close_image($dokument, $im2);
```

Comment: This is useful, but I am looking for something different. I updated the post to be a little more clear. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score -1):

I ran into the same problem.

I have several PDFs where the content of the PDF, that is text and images, go very near the PDFs border but still the print dialogue Preview/Acrobat suggests printing it in 100% scaling, thus cutting off the contents which aren't printable because of the printers natural margins.

Creating any PDF in Pages for example results in a PDF which is printed in 100% scaling by default.

However if I create a PDF using TCPDF which is related to FPDF than the printer dialog suggests to scale it in order to fit the page.

My suspicion is that the way the PDF is created is different. I suspect that Pages and other tools create separate layers and they are then handeled differently, possibly by a flag or something.

I compared the readable parts of my two PDF-Files and did come accross some differences, especially on how the documents begin. My knowledge of the PDF-Sources is, however very limited, so I can only guess what needs to change.
Is there a PDF-Reference where it is stated how to control the printable objects/areas?

Here the content of a minimal PDF which will be printed without scaling:

```
%PDF-1.4
1 0 obj
<< /Type /Catalog
/Outlines 2 0 R
/Pages 3 0 R
>>
endobj
2 0 obj
<< /Type /Outlines
/Count 0
>>
endobj
3 0 obj
<< /Type /Pages
/Kids [4 0 R]
/Count 1
>>
endobj
4 0 obj
<< /Type /Page
/Parent 3 0 R
/MediaBox [0 0 595 842]
/Contents 5 0 R
/Resources << /ProcSet 6 0 R
/Font << /F1 7 0 R >>
>>
>>
endobj
5 0 obj
<< /Length 73 >>
stream
BT
/F1 24 Tf
100 100 Td
(Hello World) Tj
ET
endstream
endobj
6 0 obj
[ /PDF /Text ]
endobj
7 0 obj
<< /Type /Font
/Subtype /Type1
/Name /F1
/BaseFont /Helvetica
/Encoding /MacRomanEncoding
>>
endobj
xref
0 8
0000000000 65535 f
0000000009 00000 n
0000000074 00000 n
0000000120 00000 n
0000000179 00000 n
0000000364 00000 n
0000000466 00000 n
0000000496 00000 n
trailer
<< /Size 8
/Root 1 0 R
>>
startxref
625
%%EOF
```

Answer (score -1):

Ok, I think I got it.
Try this: open your TCPDF-created PDF and remove all occurenecs of viewerpreferences and any box-statements other than the MediaBox... doing so finally resulted in a print-default-scaling-free PDF :)
seams like those additional infos -intended for professional printing- only confuse the common pdf-viewer instead of helping with anything :)

Goto tcpdf.php and change line 8529 in method _putpages as follows

change

```
$boxes = array('MediaBox', 'CropBox', 'BleedBox', 'TrimBox', 'ArtBox');
```

into

```
$boxes = array('MediaBox');
```

In my PDF-output this instantly removed the scaling problem :)