# Disable "Fit to Page" in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, pdf, printing, google-chrome-extension

My company has a web application that outputs a PDF which we print on label paper (stickers with product data).

Chrome is the default browser around here. Unfortunately, when we try to print from Chrome the "Fit to Page" checkbox is automatically selected. This screws up the alignment and prints data in the wrong places. If we uncheck 'Fit to Page', it prints perfectly on all machines.

If I skip the Chrome Print dialog and use the system one, it works fine on a Mac, but poorly on Windows machines.

I would really like a way to disable the "Fit to Page" option.

What I've looked at:

[Printing Avery 5160 labels with FPDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8235262/printing-avery-5160-labels-with-fpdf?lq=1)  - I added `/ViewerPreferences << /PrintScaling /None >>` to my pdf, but this article [Set PDF to print with no scaling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4725711/set-pdf-to-print-with-no-scaling) says that it's controlled by the application (Chrome in my case).

http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/REy2n67B1fM --not helpful
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=158752 --not helpful

So I'm afraid that I may need to find or make a Chrome extension to do this. Before I dig into that, does anyone know if it's even possible?

Other Facts:

PDF is being generated by `fpdf` in `php`. All computers should be using latest vs of Chrome.

Comment: The [PDF Viewer Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pdf-viewer/oemmndcbldboiebfnladdacbdfmadadm) uses the [PDF.js](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js) rendering engine to render PDFs, and display the result in the browser. To see what's going to be printed, open the developer tools (F12), click on the gears icon in the bottom-right corner, click on Overrides, and choose "Emulate CSS media print" (or use Chrome's built-in print preview, not available on Chromium though). If the result is close, but not right, tweak the print style sheet to fine-tune the result.

Comment: FYI still an open issue reported here: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=158752

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hate to say this but, could you try opening the PDF in a different browser, or use a standalone PDF reader application?

Since the Chromium team has labelled this as a `WontFix`, Chrome simply might not suffice for your needs.

Comment: Well, I'm going to go ahead and simply download the file. While Chrome ignores the pdf's `PrintScaling` flag, Acrobat reader accepts it and prints correctly by default. I found info on setting that flag here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4725711/set-pdf-to-print-with-no-scaling in the answer by @onosenday

Comment: @TimSum That issue has been resolved (it's now status: Fixed). Fit-to-page is now unchecked if all pages have the same size.

Comment: I came here looking for an answer to how I can make fit-to-page a default setting :( .. can't really find how.