# Disable auto-rotate and center in PDF files

Tags: php, pdf, pdf-generation, fpdf

I have a PHP script that uses [FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/) to create PDF files with exact dimensions (mailing labels). Problem is, when they are printed, the default options throw off all the margins and shrink everything. If the user changes "Page Scaling" to none and unchecks "Auto-Rotate and Center" the document prints perfectly. Problem with that solution is, nobody remembers to do it.

I found another question on SO with [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8062099/562697) that helps by defaulting the "Page Scaling" to none by adding a `ViewerPreferences` tag with `PrintScaling` option.

Does anybody know of a similar tag/option that I can add to the PDF to uncheck "Auto-Rotate and Center" by default?

Comment: Super, I got Tumbleweed for this question.

Comment: http://www.fpdf.de/downloads/addons/36/ would something like this help. And is the auto rotate option available to all printers?

Comment: How about this [answer by "Dave Merchant" in Adobe forums](http://forums.adobe.com/message/4137601) on adjusting the page scaling and a few other options so that "Auto Rotate and Center" and/or the new version of that has no effect.

Comment: I can't adjust the page scaling or other similar options because all the alignments are exact so they print on the labels correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is mostly on the users end, it's hard to enforce with PDF.  A workaround I can think off would be to put a thin black border around the page.  This would prevent any rotation as it would detect it as being straight, and if you put the border right on the margin it could just work out.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I stopped getting notified about this question. I am less concerned about the rotation, I don't think that is happening, but the document is centered and it shifts the margins.