# FPDF force print to "Fit to Page"

Tags: fpdf

Is it possible using FPDF to force the print diaglog to default to 'Fit to Page' in Adobe Reader's page scaling? I am currently working with an existing document that is 8.27" x 11.67", and rather than rewriting it to squeeze the extra .67" out of it, I'd like to set a value to make Adobe Reader set the scale to "Fit to Page" by default.

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4725711/set-pdf-to-print-with-no-scaling

Answer (score 0):

how about you set the page in A4 size like ' $pdf=new FPDF('P','mm','A4');`

Comment: Not a possible solution because the printers that will be handling these PDFs once created do not have an A4 tray.

Comment: why don't you change the paper layout based on your printer like 'A5, A3, etc'?... by the way $pdf=new FPDF('potrait(P)/landscape(L), 'size of paper', 'paper layout');

Comment: It needs to be portrait on letter, we are printing to a number of different printers throughout the company.