# How to set fit to page view when opening a PDF file in browser using Zend_Pdf

Tags: pdf, zend-pdf

I am using Zend_Pdf to create PDF documents. Is there a method in Zend_Pdf to set the view as *fit to page* (or fit to the user's screen to be exact) when opening the PDF file in a browser? Like mpdf's SetDisplayMode("fullpage") function.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm quite familiar with the `Zend_Pdf` API and I'm pretty sure that this option doesn't exist. I also did a search on "ViewerPreferences" in the code and nothing came up. "ViewerPreferences" is part of the string that would need to exist in the file if this option existed, so the omission of this string further suggests that this option isn't supported in `Zend_Pdf`.

This answer provides some good tips that might allow somebody to implement the option in `Zend_Pdf` though: [Set PDF to print with no scaling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4725711/set-pdf-to-print-with-no-scaling)